# Can PDFBox return incorrect X and Y Coordinates for a character?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox to extract text and X & Y coordinates of all the characters of our company Invoices which are in a specific format.

I ran various test on multiple PDFs and have manually tested for the past 2 weeks to find the return of incorrect coordinates by PDFBox and so far the results are accurate. All tests were done manually by using Gimp to open the PDF file and comparing the X & Y coordinates produced by PDFBox and Gimp.

**Question:**
Because having accurate coordinates is very crucial for my Java application, I Just wanted to know if there is a possibility for PDFBox to return incorrect coordinates ?

Comment: How do you define *incorrect*? Different PDF viewers / processors may assume some given text to be located at different positions in case of extreme values being used in the matrices of the underlying affine transformations due to differing accuracies of the used floating point numbers or differing calculation optimizations. None of those viewers or processors needs to be wrong in that situation. If no such extreme values are used, though, discrepancies would indicate some error in at least one of the compared viewers / processors.

Comment: Just the differences between the text, the spaces etc should be right. I'm not looking for a text at a specific coordinate. For eg: if there is a table and tables heading says X and Y coordinate for this heading is between 100,200 and 130,200 ... and the content is guarantee to be in between only under the heading then the content's x and Y coordinates should always be between 100,200 and 130,200

Comment: PDFBox is quite thorough here. There may be bugs, though, and there may be horribly broken PDFs offering differing interpretations. But I'm not aware of them.